# (-215:Assertion failed) corr.rows <= img.rows + templ.rows - 1 && corr.cols <= img.cols + templ.cols - 1 in function 'cv::crossCorr' (matchTemplate)

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I've run into issues with `win32gui` when trying to grab a real-time video stream of an application. I've seen I can use ImageGrab from PIL and based on this video [Computer Screen Recording using Python & OpenCV](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GWdrL8dt1xQ) I think I can use it instead of `win32gui`

I'm trying to learn python by writing a bot, the below code should grab images from a specified folder, load them into an array, converts them into a format OpenCV can use and then attempts to find any or all of them on my application window `haystack`

I can't find any details on google of the error I'm getting:

```
C:\Users\coyle\OneDrive\froggy-pirate-master\avoidShips>C:/Users/coyle/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Users/coyle/OneDrive/froggy-pirate-master/avoidShips/avoidships4.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\coyle\OneDrive\froggy-pirate-master\avoidShips\avoidships4.py", line 41, in <module>
    loadImages()
  File "c:\Users\coyle\OneDrive\froggy-pirate-master\avoidShips\avoidships4.py", line 22, in loadImages
    return matchTemplate(image_list)
  File "c:\Users\coyle\OneDrive\froggy-pirate-master\avoidShips\avoidships4.py", line 32, in matchTemplate
    result = cv.matchTemplate(haystack, needle_img, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-wvn_it83\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\templmatch.cpp:588: error: (-215:Assertion failed) corr.rows <= img.rows + templ.rows - 1 && corr.cols <= img.cols + templ.cols - 1 in function 'cv::crossCorr'
```

And my code:

```
def loadImages():
    # Intialise empty array
    image_list = []
    # Get list of all images in directory
    directory = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\*.png")

    # Add images to image_list
    for img in directory:
        ship_img = cv.imread(img, 0)
        image_list.append(ship_img)
    return matchTemplate(image_list)

def matchTemplate(image_list):
    # Video Loop
    while True:
        haystack_img = ImageGrab.grab()
        haystack_img_np = np.array(haystack_img)
        haystack = cv.cvtColor(haystack_img_np, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        
        # Object Detection
        for ships in image_list:
            needle_img = cv.imread(str(image_list), cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
            result = cv.matchTemplate(haystack, needle_img, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
            cv.imshow('Result', haystack)

            if cv.waitKey(1) == 27:
                break

        cv.destroyAllWindows()

loadImages()
matchTemplate()
```

As a test, I've tried doing the same thing using static images and it works so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
import cv2 as cv
import glob

# load source images
directory = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\*.jpg')
# empty list to store the source images
image_list = []

for img in directory:
    ships_img = cv.imread(img, 0)
    image_list.append(ships_img)

haystack_img = cv.imread(r'C:\Users\both.jpg')
haystack_img = cv.cvtColor(haystack_img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#loop for matching
for ships in image_list:
    
    #save the dimensions of the needle images
    (H, W) = ships.shape[:2]
    result = cv.matchTemplate(haystack_img, ships, cv.TM_CCOEFF)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv.minMaxLoc(result)
    top_left = max_loc
    
    bottom_right = (top_left[0] + W, top_left[1] + H)
    cv.rectangle(haystack_img, top_left, bottom_right, 255, 2)

cv.imshow('Result', haystack_img)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: the exception says that the template is too large, or the haystack is too small. check the shapes of haystack and needle_img at the time of the exception (just print them always before the call)

Comment: previous question (*with no accepted answer* and lots of confusion...), with a title identical to what I would have given this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68225508/matchtemplate-215assertion-failed-corr-rows-img-rows-templ-rows-1

Comment: I'm dumped `cv.imshow("Screen", haystack_img_np)` after I convert the `ImageGrab` to my np array and the python window opens up correctly but it immediately (doesn't show anything) goes not responding. Any ideas @ChristophRackwitz

Comment: I've done some testing outside of my functions in a new script (functions always seem to cause me issues) and the issue is definitely `result = cv.matchTemplate(haystack, needle_img, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)` When I print(needle_img) as you've suggested I get back `none` so I think my problem is how I'm reading the images because `image_list` shows as an array in the debugger I.e. `array([[70, 70, 70, ..., 46, 46, 46],`

Comment: so? continue investigating the None result. use `os.path.isfile`. keep going.

Comment: you use `imread(str(image_lst))` so you try to send list with many elements but it needs single element - single filename. Other problem is that this list has aready loaded images you try to use image data to load it again in `imread()` - it is wrong. You should use directly `needle_img = ship` instead of `needle_img = cv.imread(str(image_list), ...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test it but you simply try to load image which you already have in memory

You have

```
needle_img = cv.imread(str(image_list), cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

but `image_list` has already loaded image, not filenames.
Besides `imread()` needs sinlge `filename` but you try use it with some `list` converted to string.

You should use directly

```
needle_img = ships
```

---

I think it should be

```
def loadImages():
    # Intialise empty array
    image_list = []
    
    # Get list of all images in directory
    directory = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\*.png")

    # Add images to image_list
    for img in directory:
        ship_img = cv.imread(img, 0)  # <-- here you load all images
        image_list.append(ship_img)
        
    return image_list   # I preferr to send back data instead of running `matchTemplate`


def matchTemplate(image_list):
    # Video Loop
    while True:
        haystack_img = ImageGrab.grab()
        haystack_img_np = np.array(haystack_img)
        haystack = cv.cvtColor(haystack_img_np, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        
        # Object Detection
        for ships in image_list:
            # you don't have to load images because you already have them in `image_list`
            #needle_img = cv.imread(str(image_list), cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
            
            needle_img = ships
            
            result = cv.matchTemplate(haystack, needle_img, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
            cv.imshow('Result', haystack)

            if cv.waitKey(1) == 27:
                break

        cv.destroyAllWindows()

# --- main ---

image_list = loadImages()
matchTemplate(image_list)
```

---

**BTW:**

In normal `open()`, `read()` you get error if it has problem to open or read file but in OpenCV `imread()` does't raise error when it can't load image but it gives `None` - but you don't check if you get `None` - and you don't know that there was problem to load it - and later when you try to use this value in next command (`matchTemplate`) then it shows error. But real problem was with `imread()`

Comment: Thanks for the detail @Furas I'll take a look at this a little later today but that all makes sense for now! Thank you!

Comment: Yup, nailed it. That all makes sense. It's working! Not to figure out how to speed up the window capture, it's deathly slow. Thank you!